# how to add Header in action popup

Tags: android

[Popup Library](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

---

**I have to display my own header in popup and it**

---

[image: sample Screen]

```
          here + sign and back arrow is header i want to exactly  like this
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Costume Dialog like below

```
public class dialogMesssageType {
    Dialog dialog;
    Context m_context;
    Activity act;

    public void showDialog(Activity activity, Context context, final String titre, final String message, final int type) {
        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        m_context = context;
        act = activity;
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_message_type);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));


        TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        TextView titre_id = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_titre);
        TextView ok = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirmation);



        ImageView img_type(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_type);
        ImageView close = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

        txt.setText(message);
        titre_id.setText(titre);


        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }


}
```

xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_gray"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/blue_neigra"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_type"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_titre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Warning"
        android:textColor="#039470"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please fill in all fields"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:background="@color/blue_neigra"></View>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/confirmation"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_neigra"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Ok"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_blue_gray_cercle"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/close_blue" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

i removed Animation .

Comment: please give me the all required file is use in this code,dialog_message_type.xml ,anim folder...